# How to create an event listener for an event raised from another class

Tags: vb.net, events

I'm trying to create a generic listener/handler in my main form for an event raised from a class (on another file). I'm trying to do so because i need access to my form labels (and the instance of this class has to be global, so i can't declare it in my form class).

The final goal is to create DataBindings between the "Text" property of a label and a string/property, on the instance creation (which raises an event).

On my class StaticScaleDetails:

```
Public Class StaticScaleDetails
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event CreatedNewScale()

    Private _ipAddress As String

    Public Property ipAddress
        Get
            Return _ipAddress
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _ipAddress = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("ipAddress"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New(ByVal ip As String)
        ipAddress = ip

        RaiseEvent CreatedNewScale()
    End Sub

    Public Sub AssociateHandlers(ByRef ipObject As Object)
        ipObject.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me, "ipAddress"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

I need some way from my Form class to handle the "CreatedNewScale()" event. Any ideas?

P.S.: I probably need to create a List of StaticScaleDetails instances, so i'd rather not use a handler only for a specific instance.

Comment: You'll need to call AddHandler for each instance. If you plan on having a list, then the list could handle the event and throw it's own event.

Comment: Try declaring a static event. You can subscribe it once and it's raised each time a new instance of the class is created, if you `.Invoke` it in the instance contructor.

Comment: @the_lotus Thank you, in the end i did need a list, so i managed to create and add only one handler. I couldn't upvote your comment because i'm new, i'll do it as soon as i'll be able to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i found the solution: i needed a list, so i created it and added only one event handler for the list object:

In a module containing some global variables, i declared

```
Public StaticScales As New BindingList(Of StaticScaleDetails)
```

so that it could be accessed from everywhere.

I added an event handler in my Main:

```
Private LastIndex As Integer 'Variable to keep track of the size the list was the last time the event has been triggered

Private Sub ListIsChanged()
    If StaticScales.Count > LastIndex And StaticScales.Count <= 5 Then
        'Console.WriteLine("The list has changed: its size changed from {0} to {1}!", LastIndex, StaticScales.Count)

        SelectLabelsToAssociate()
        LastIndex = StaticScales.Count
    End If
End Sub
```

And on the Load of my Main:

```
LastIndex = 0
AddHandler StaticScales.ListChanged, AddressOf ListIsChanged
```

There are probably more "elegant" solutions (like creating a custom class which triggers the event only when an item is added instead of when the list is changed in any way), but this way it works.